# Making Video run one after another like in youtube playlist style using android

Tags: android, video, youtube

I want to make video list interface that look like in youtube playlist which we can play 1 video and after finished it automatically play next video on the playlist. And we have the list of video, then if we click the video it will play inside the player.

Can we achieve something like that? I only able to play one video inside 1 player, OR using 1 player (with next and prev button overlay the video) to play whole playlist, but this way, we cannot see what the video list on the playlist

Comment: You should look into [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html), it's what YouTube uses.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it now